# ubuntu iptables doesn't block wget

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall

Please, help me to understand what I'm doing wrong with **iptables** on ubuntu 14.04.

```
iptables -F
ip6tables -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP
ip6tables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

# allows the outgoing traffic of established connections, necessary if the OUTPUT policy is not set to ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

**iptables -nvL**

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
10574   17M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    2    88 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
  260 14124 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
10317  623K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

In the above I try to block all except ssh. So, I expect that wget won't be able to download anything, but it works and apt-get update doesn't work (as expected). Please, explain me how to block all (incoming/outgoing), or if this configuration is ok, why wget is still working?

EDIT: Also I tried to change 2 lines to one, but it does't help.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Result: wget is working, apt-get update no. Could someone clarify why?
Thanks.

Comment: Is `wget` using a proxy?  A different interface?  Please show a sample successful `wget` to see what connection(s) it makes.

Comment: Don't know about proxy, I didn't do any configuration of wget. There is only one eth0 except lo. CSample: 

Resolving repo1.maven.org (repo1.maven.org)... 151.101.20.209
Connecting to repo1.maven.org (repo1.maven.org)|151.101.20.209|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 8870813 (8.5M) [application/java-archive]
Saving to: Б─≤wiremock-standalone-2.1.11.jarБ─≥

100%[=========================================================================>] 8,870,813    654KB/s   in 14s

Comment: make sure the rules are actually loaded with `iptables -nvL` and paste the output, also please include the output of `curl -vI www.google.com` in the original question.

Comment: sure, incoming ports closed, so web service which working on ubuntu isn't available via https for example.

Comment: Rabin, added in question

Comment: What are you attempting to do with the ` --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED ` rule?

Comment: I agree with @JigglyNaga what is the purpose of --cstate NEW,ESTABLISHED in the OUTPUT chain? This rule allow all the outgoing traffic

Comment: Without it I cannot connect via putty, or opened https cannot be reachable. I checked it right now. --ctstate ESTABLISHED without NEW would be ok, but without this rule at all no.

Comment: Putty is ssh, which should be handled by the port 22 rules and the `ESTABLISHED` ones.  You didn't mention in the question that you wanted https as well - do you want wget to be able to download over https?

Comment: If "ESTABLISHED without NEW would be ok", why did you include "NEW"?

Comment: I just want to open ssh and https ports for in/out, sorry I didn't realize that https in question makes sense

Comment: To help find a solution, you should [edit the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/307402/edit) to include some more information: (1) that you also want HTTPS, and (2) the purpose of your `iptables` commands (especially the `cstate` ones).  If you're following instructions found elsewhere, please link to them so we can see whether they're right for your needs.

Comment: 1. Https doesn't makes sense here, because the question is not about allowing it, currently about ssh only because ssh doesn't work without ctstate.
2. According to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands

Comment: Please don't post [the same question in two places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286903/ubuntu-iptables-doesnt-block-wget)

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your rules and requirements block by block. You've got a default policy of `DROP` so you don't need the final rule. (It's not a bad idea, though.)

> I try to block all except ssh. So, I expect that `wget` won't be able to download anything, but it works and `apt-get update` doesn't work (as expected)

Input rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

What that says is that any traffic related to an outgoing connection is to be permitted. And anything inbound to tcp/22 (i.e. `ssh`) is also to be permitted. Everything else should be dropped. Note that nothing here blocks your outgoing `wget` and `apt-get update` requests.

Output rules:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

What this says is that any traffic related to a previously permitted inbound connection is to be permitted. And anything outbound to a destination tcp/22 (i.e. `ssh`) is also to be permitted. Finally, everything else should be dropped.

Observations:

Nothing in the outbound section permits your `wget` or `apt-get update` requests. Therefore, if `wget` is working then please provide the example command you're using, along with the output of `set | grep _proxy`. (You may see one or more definitions such as `http_proxy`, which define a proxy for each corresponding protocol.)

---

By the way, recommended practice for `iptables` is to allow all loopback traffic, which you can do with these two commands:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Default in/out policies is to DROP, and http/https not accepted, only 22 should be opened. So, question is not disappear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check on fresh installation a little bit later. 
About loopback - I know, but in case if it doesn't needed, it is cannot be recommended anyway. It depends on situation.